# Trying to compare the dates in two columns and if 18 years or younger color the cell red

Tags: excel, vba

"here is what I have so far, coloring the whole column red"

"Trying to subtract date in column K from column M and if less than 18 years, indicating a minor, than color cell in column K red."

```
Dim N As Long, i As Long
Dim NewDate As Date

  
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
NewDate = DateAdd("yyyy", -18, Date)

For i = 2 To N
        
    If NewDate < Cells(i, "M").Value Then
        Cells(i, "K").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
            
Next i
```

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting?

Comment: And what problem does the above code? Are there years after 2003 and the cell keeping them becomes red, too? Do the compared cells keep born dates?

Comment: Should `CDate("13.09.2004")` from the cell be red or not? The same for `CDate("13.09.2002")`...

Comment: Sorry everyone I guess my explanation is bad.  What I want to do is compare date in column M and date in column K, If the two dates are less than 18 years apart, color the cell in column K red, indicating a minor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using [`DateSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function):

```
For i = 2 To N
    Dim OldDate As Date
    OldDate = Cells(i, "K").Value
        
    If DateSerial(Year(OldDate) + 18, Month(OldDate), Day(OldDate)) > Cells(i, "M").Value Then
        Cells(i, "K").Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If            
Next
```

This can be done with conditional formatting too, using a rule based on the formula:

```
=M2<DATE(YEAR(K2)+18,MONTH(K2),DAY(K2))
```

applied to the cells in column K starting in row 2.